# Beautifulsoup unable to find more than 24 classes with find_all

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to scape data from page where all the items are stored like this

`<div class="box browsingitem canBuy 123"> </div>
 <div class="box browsingitem canBuy 264"> </div>`

There are hundreds of these but when I try to add them into array it only saves 24

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
import lxml

my_url = 'https://www.alza.co.uk/tablets/18852388.htm'


uClient = uReq(my_url)

page_html = uClient.read()

uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "lxml")

classname = "box browsingitem"
containers = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class":re.compile(classname)})

#len(containers) will be equal to 24

for container in containers:    
    title_container = container.find_all("a",{"class":"name browsinglink"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text  
    print("product_name: " + product_name)
```

Is it a problem with re.compile? How else could I search for the classes?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is it possible that those hundreds are loaded on scrolling?

Comment: If all of those items contain the class names `box browsingitem`, why not just do `page_soup.find_all('div', 'box browsingitem')`. That should  retrieve all the items of that class that are loaded in the DOM.

Comment: @taras it is but it load 24 for example even when there is 18 items... really weird

Comment: @Steven for some reason it doesn't work, it loads 0

Comment: Can you provide the link you're trying to scrape? @Blayss

Comment: @Steven Edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in this case, only 24 items are loaded in the DOM when you visit the page. The two options that occur to me are 1) use a headless browser to click the "load more" button and load more items onto the DOM or 2) create a simple pagination scheme and loop through those pages.

Here is an example of the second option:

```
for page in range(0, 10):
    print("Trying page # {}".format(page))
    if page == 0:
        my_url = 'https://www.alza.co.uk/tablets/18852388.html'
    else: 
        my_url = 'https://www.alza.co.uk/tablets/18852388-p{}.html'.format(page)
        requests.get(my_url)

    page_html = requests.get(my_url)
    page_soup = soup(page_html.content, "lxml")
    items = page_soup.find_all('div', {"class": "browsingitem"})
    print("Found a total of {}".format(len(items)))
    for item in items:
        title  = page_soup.find('a', 'browsinglink')
```

You can see that the URLs have the pagination information built in, so all you need to do is determine how many pages you want to scrape, and you can save all that information. Here is the output:

```
Trying page # 0
Found a total of 24
Trying page # 1
Found a total of 24
Trying page # 2
Found a total of 24
Trying page # 3
Found a total of 24
Trying page # 4
Found a total of 24
Trying page # 5
Found a total of 24
Trying page # 6
Found a total of 24
Trying page # 7
Found a total of 24
Trying page # 8
Found a total of 17
Trying page # 9
Found a total of 0
```